# Solving for $x$ : $a^x+b^x=c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function, roots, newton-raphson

> Well the question is to solve for $x$ in $$a^x+b^x=c \tag{a,b,c are constants}$$

Well as of me, I tried to put $\ln{}$ on both sides which does not seem to help. Apart from this I don't seem to have any other way to solve it.

I turned to WolframAlpha and the solution which was given was :
$$x=\dfrac{-i(2\pi n +\pi)}{\ln{a}-\ln{b}} , {n \in \mathbb{Z}}$$

And if $n=0$ $$x=\dfrac{-i\pi}{\ln{a}-\ln{b}}$$

The only thing I am able to recognize is $e^{i\pi}=1$ ... i guess is used.

Link : http://goo.gl/da9G01

So I see that $x$ is *independent* of the constant $c$.

So how to solve it? Please help...Thanks!

---

**EDIT** - It seems that WolframAlpha is taking $c=0$ as suggested by Donkey_2009. And when i write "Solve for x in a^x + b^x = k" it is *not* returning *anything*. So are you guys aware of a method to solve this? Also are you guys aware of any other website/software like WA?

---

**P.S.** - Also I see that IF we know the values of $a,b,c$ resulting in something like $2^x+3^x=100$ , then *Newton's method* is the only method I am aware of that can solve it...

**Any other suggestions?**

Comment: Doesn't seem like the solution is, in general, constructible.

Comment: Has Wolfram ever been wrong before?

Comment: @user3728501 I guess once/twice. But ... its rare.

Comment: I have tested the page with much more simpler equations like $m=a\cdot x$. It seems that the web page is not supposed to solve equations.

Comment: @ajotatxe WolframAlpha is VERY much supposed to be able to solve equations....Try this : Solve for x in m=ax [Link: http://goo.gl/j5HAEm]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*See edit below*

I don't think the solution should be independent of $c$.  Maybe you typed into Wolfram

$$
a^x+b^x=0
$$

In that case, it's not too hard to see where the solution comes from.  Move $b^x$ to one side to get:
\begin{align}
b^x&=-a^x\\
&=(-1)\times a^x\\
&=e^{i\pi}a^x
\end{align}
Then take $\ln$ of both sides:
$$
x\ln(b)=i\pi +x\ln(a)
$$
from which it follows easily that
$$
x=\frac{-i\pi}{\ln(a)-\ln(b)}
$$
The other solutions come from using the fact that we have:
$$
e^{i(2n\pi+\pi)}=(e^{i\pi})^{2n+1}=(-1)^{2n+1}=-1
$$
so we can replace $e^{i\pi}$ with $e^{i(2n\pi+\pi)}$ above and get another solution.

---

If we no longer insist that $c=0$ then we won't get such a nice solution.  This is not unusual in mathematics.  Even nice polynomial equations like $x^5+x+1=0$ don't have solutions that can be written in terms of nice functions.

---

**Edit:** I've just see your link, and it looks as if you've misunderstood Wolfram's answer.  You typed in
$$
c=a^x+b^x
$$
and Wolfram Alpha interpreted this as $c$ being a function of $x$, where $a, b$ are constants.  The value 
$$
x=\frac{-i\pi}{\ln(a)-\ln(b)}
$$
is listed as a *root* of this equation, i.e., a value of $x$ that makes $c$ equal to $0$.  So we are effectively solving
$$
a^x+b^x=0
$$
for $x$.

As an example, if you typed in
$$
y=x^2-5x+6
$$
then a *root* of this equation would be a value of $x$ such that $x^2-5x+6=0$.

Comment: Check the link I gave :)

Comment: Downvoters - any improvements I can make? :)

Comment: Do you know of any other websites/softwares which functions similarly to WA?

Comment: Why do you ask?  Are you unhappy with the answer you got from them?  As I have tried to explain, it is completely correct.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solve, just an idea. This is for $a^x+b^x=0$ by the way.
$$a^x=-b^x$$
$$\log_ax=-\log_bx$$
$$\frac{\ln x}{\ln a}=-\frac{\ln x}{\ln b}$$
$$\ln a=- \ln b$$
$$x=\frac{-i \pi}{ln(a)-ln(b)}$$ 
$$x=\frac{-i \pi}{2\ln(a)}$$
$$2x\ln (a)=-i \pi$$
$$e^{2x\ln (a)}=e^{-i \pi}$$
$$e^{2x\ln (a)}=-1$$